# Convert an imported date from excel into a format that mathematica can recognize

Tags: pattern-matching, date-and-time

`ToString[dates1[[1]]]` yields the following:

`"DateObject[{2006, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, Instant, Gregorian, -5.]"`

I would like to convert the the imported list `dates1` to:

`"DateObject[{2006, 10, 5}, Day, Gregorian, -5.]"`

Ultimately my goal is to extract specific dates using `Position[]` so I can identify ranges of dates within the data.

Comment: No need to convert anything: `Position[dates1, DateObject[{your, date, here, ___}, ___]]` should be all you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the trick I needed.

Comment: @JeremiahStafford how could that be the case if you say you have strings there: `"..."`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
obj = Characters[
  "DateObject[{2006, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, Instant, Gregorian, -5.]"];
```

then

```
StringInsert[
 StringJoin[Drop[Characters[obj], {26, 45}]], "}, Day,", {25}]

(*  "DateObject[{2006, 10, 5,}, Day, Gregorian, -5.]"  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll dig into this a bit, the first solution solved my issue. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

As [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1) notes in [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162408/convert-an-imported-date-from-excel-into-a-format-that-mathematica-can-recognize#comment430781_162408), you can extract positions of specific dates using usual patterns, no need to convert date objects to strings:

```
Position[dates1, DateObject[{your, date, here, ___}, ___]]
```